# Значение и происхождение слова «могутно»

Tags: этимология, лексика, грамматика, диалекты

> Воще-то это вика, — вставил Крапивка. — Вы что, люпина не видели или как? Но в одном вы правы, милсдарь. **Родиться здесь *могутно* и растет — глядеть приятственно.**

Является ли слово *могутно* чистой стилизацией или это вполне себе закономерная диалектная форма? Что она значит, как ее можно грамматически охарактеризовать и каково ее происхождение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О происхождении нам Фасмер расскажет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А толковый словарь даст к слову помету: народно-поэтическое, т. е. для современной нормативной речи да в бытовой беседе безусловно стилизация, не диалект.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

> **МОГУТНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -тен, -тна, -тно. *Нар.-поэт.* Физически сильный, крепкий; могучий. *М-ые плечи. М. мужчина.* ◆ *[Могутный был
>   человек поп Мирон: косая сажень в плечах, а голова, как пивной
>   котел.](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)* Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк, «Охонины брови», 1892 г.

Как диалектное могло сохраниться и по сей день - хоть в той же Фасмером упомянутой Архангельской области.

МОГУТНО - наречие от *могутный:* мощно (для посевов - дружно, всходчиво).

---

> Гов**о**ря – это язык варягов-руси, беломорских поморов,
>   старообрядцев поморского толка и соловецких монахов, язык северных
>   русских ремесленников и промышленников, сказочников и первопроходцев
>   Сибири и Арктики. Поморска гов**о**ря – это язык древних былин,
>   песен и сказок, ***в недавнем прошлом на нем говорили онежане,
>   мезенцы, пинежане, каргопольцы, шенкуряне***. Поморская гов**о**ря
>   имеет такие особенности, которые выводят ее из разряда обычных
>   диалектов русского языка и позволяют рассматривать как один из
>   древнейших арийских языков.

[Слова из поморской говори, которых нет в современном русском языке](http://ukhtoma.ru/chud11.htm)

**Голоменой царь**

> Во досюлишны-от веки, во которы-то давношни леты, унёсло во пылко
>   морьско голомё коць с кулояна. Било морё их цетвёры воды, а на
>   петой-от день тиха пала погодьё. Омалталиссе кулояна, гленули – тако
>   лосо на мори, вода кротка, одаль каменна луда, а серёдка луды трои
>   полохола сидят - шолнцё, ветёр да мороз. Меж има котора идет: которой
>   из их большак на мори?
>
> Увидали трои полохола кулоян-от, ко луды коць потташшили, оприколили,
>   крицят:  – Сказывайте скоре, которой меж нама самой **могутной** на мори?
>   Которого нарецете, тот из нас на голомено царьство настанет.
>
> Кулояна не долго меж собою поредили, да и ответ дёржат:  – Вы все трои
>   **могутны**, а большак-от у вас один – ветёр. Он и есь голоменой царь.
>
> Тут мороз осердилссе, пал на кулоян, хотел застудить-заморозить.  А
>   ветёр им:  - Не бойтиссё, я дуть не стану, дак мороз-от без ветру не
>   порато морозлив.  Не стал дуть ветёр, мороз окротел,
>   пошшипалл-пошшипал, да и оступилссе от кулоян.
>
> А тут шолнцё взъерилоссе, стало жгать да жарить.  А ветёр опеть
>   затёшшат: – Не бойтиссё, я подую, дак с ветерьём-от шолнцё не порато
>   жарит.  Пал ветёр на лосо морё, шолнцё и оступилоссе.
>
> Ветром оттулило коць от каменной луды. Поднели кулояна на поветёрь
>   парус, да скорёхонько ко дому-то и добежали.  А ветёр-от и взаболь на
>   мори **могутне** всех – он-от над всема вёрьхову дёржжит.